# QPlainTextEdit and line numbers

Tags: qt

A need exaple how this work. I read doc for QPlainTextEdit and google but examples on google is old and dont work in current version...
Am making code editor i have expiriance in QT but no realy good.

Am looking who can explain me how can make that.

QPlainTextEdit and row(line number).

Answer (score 1):

[this](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/widgets-codeeditor.html) is a simple editor that has line numbers.

Comment: Guys do u have any simple example. I try example @liuyi but dot work. How that work any1 explain me and i make that. I need idea.